# Hidden Field values changed in javascript don't get reflected at server in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control having a hidden field that gets set on the node click of a Tree View Hierarchy control. The underlying function for the click event of the Tree View is:

```
function OnTreeClick(evt) {
     var src = window.event != window.undefined ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target;
     var nodeClick = src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a";

     var treeImages = evt.srcElement.alt;
     if (nodeClick) {
         $("#HierarchyOriginSource").val("TreeViewNode");
      }
}
```

I am dynamically adding the onclick client attribute during the PreRender phase of the User Control like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tvwHierarchy.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OnTreeClick(event);");
}
```

When a user clicks a node of the Tree View control the Hidden Field value is set to "TreeViewNode".

In all versions of IE, I can debug and see the value of the Hidden field gets changed as expected from the client side and I can retrieve that value from within the User Control on the server side.

But when tested in Chrome the new value is not reflected. Initially I noted the behavior and tried a suggestion offered on another post to place the hidden field controls inside of an update panel but that doesn't appear to work either.

Why does the changed value show for IE browsers and not Chrome? Is there a work around?

Comment: You're missing a closing curly on the `nodeClick` conditional.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in the question. I edited it. The code actually has the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

May there is an exception occurred in the chrome. That's why its not updating the value of hidden field. You cannot change the value of hidden field if it is out of update-panel because view-state not update completely in partial post back